# how to write python to replace the next perl code?

Tags: python

I have just encountered Perl code similar to the following:

```
my @keys = qw/ 1 2 3 /;
my @vals = qw/ a b c /;
my %hash;
@hash{@keys} = @vals;
```

This code populates an associative array given a list of keys and a list of values. For example, the above code creates the following data structure (expressed as JSON):

```
{
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c"
}
```

How would one go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import json

keys = [1, 2, 3]
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']
hash = dict(zip(keys, vals))

json.dumps(hash)
=> '{"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

That json is pretty much a polyglot with Python.  Once you assign it to a name, though, it stops being a polyglot.

```
hf = {
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c"
}
```

You can also iteratively align items into a dictionary.

```
letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', )
numbers = ('1', '2', '3', )
hf = { n : l for n, l in zip(numbers, letters) }
```

Comment: or `hash = dict(zip(numbers, letters))`

Comment: Sure, to-may-comprehension-to, to-mah-functional-to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> keys='123'
>>> vals='abc'
>>> dict(zip(keys,vals))
{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b'}
```

(Python note: strings are iterable, so `list('abc')` is the rough equivalent of `my @vals = qw/ a b c /;` in Perl)

Then if you want JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(dict(zip(keys,vals)))
'{"1": "a", "3": "c", "2": "b"}'
```